# Compare in-work record values to already existing values in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I'm working on a "Maintenance" table for our Access db. My problem comes when I try to create a drop down list that shows "Employee Name" where "EmployeeLocation" is equal to "MaintenanceLocation" that is being worked on.

My code looked something like

```
SELECT Employees.EmployeeName
FROM Employees
WHERE (((Employees.EmployeeLocation)=[Maintenance].[MaintenanceLocation]));
```

but I get a window asking what the values should be. Is there a way to take the current record value for `MaintenanceLocation` and pass it so that I don't have to answer the question myself?

Edit: Ultimate goal is to show only employees for that location from `Employee` table

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what the situation is based on your question, but try this:

```sql
select e.EmployeeName
from Employees as e inner join Maintenance m 
  on e.EmployeeLocation = m.MaintenanceLocation
```

Comment: I think the easiest explanation is:
I am currently working on record 15. Since I am still filling information in, how can I get the value of attribute `MaintenanceLocation` to pull all employees from `Employee` table listed under that location? I want to be able to only display the employees listed for that specific location, not a list of all employees. The code provided only provides a list of all employees.